# Change .Text-property in designer without property-window

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, key-bindings, designer

I am pretty sure in an earlier installation of visual studio I was able to hit F2 in the winforms designer to directly change the .Text property of the selected Winforms-Control (i.e. button).

This way I did not have to switch over to the property-window to search the .Text property. A nice time saving feature.

Unfortunately my active installation of VS 2017 doesnt support this or it is not activated in the settings, which I cant find an option for.

I'd appreciate if you could name me the option if you are aware of it.

Comment: I guess you confused Visual Studio with MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F2 is typically tied to loading the Object Browser.

You should be able to select the control and start typing.  When you select a control with the Property Window open, you should see that the `Text` property is automatically selected, but not in edit mode (the cursor is not in the input box).  It jumps to edit as soon as you start typing.

Comment: Just start typing. I just did. I feel so stupid now. Pretty sure back then it showed a textbox ontop of the control in the designer. Thank you. Edit: Not exactly. It only works if .Text was selected before. But it already helps increasing efficiency.